# Python: Using Properties to Control Attribute Access

Tags: python, oop, properties, attributes

I am reading book ***Programming in Python 3***. In the Chapter of ***Object-Oriented Programming***, the author gives one example of ***using properties to control attribute access***:

```
class Circle():

    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self.__radius

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, radius):
        assert radius > 0, "radius must be nonzero and non-negative"
        self.__radius = radius
```

Why, when changing data attribute ***radius*** into a property, it becomes ***__radius***?

Could someone explicitly explain if I call: (code in Shape.py file)

```
a = Shape.Circle(2)
```

how the code will work? (which method is called first, and then, and which is last.)

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `__init__` function, the assignment `self.radius` calls `@radius.setter` function. It's that setter function which stores the value in `self.__radius`.

Example:

### source

```
class Circle(object):

    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    @property
    def radius(self):
        print 'GET'
        return self.__radius

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, radius):
        print 'SET'
        assert radius > 0, "radius must be nonzero and non-negative"
        self.__radius = radius

print 'creating circle:'
c = Circle(2)
print 'modifying radius:'
c.radius = 3
print 'verifying'
print c.radius
```

### output

```
creating circle:
SET
modifying radius:
SET
verifying
GET
3
```

Note that `SET` is called when the circle is created.  Even in the `__init__` method, the object respects the `@radius.setter` function.

**Note #2:**

Since `radius` is a property, not an attribute, you fetch/store its value directly. If you call `c.radius()` as a function.  Otherwise this:

```
c.radius()
GET
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Isn't it better to do c.radius(3) and c.radius() instead of c.radius = 3 and c.radius?

Comment: `__init__()` calls `@radius.setter` is surely the way! So after using property, the data is actually stored in `__radius` (private property) instead of `radius`.